# Swift Timer - How to stop the UIButton text from resetting?

Tags: swift, uibutton, nstimer

I have a simple Swift timer that counts down from `200` down to `50`.

The timer is set at 200 on `viewDidLoad` and is controlled by a single `UIButton` that handles the following 2 states:

1. Start timer (Start reducing from 200)
2. Stop timer (Invalidate timer and pause it)

The `UIButton` has a prefilled text: "Start", the contents of which get overwritten by the current counter number.

The problem I have is that when I press the button again to pause the timer, the UIButton's text is reset to the prefilled "Start"

I want it not to reset until the user is ready to do, by pressing a reset button (not implemented yet)

My code is as follows; I will put it into a custom UIButton class soon; I'm just want the button label to stop resetting to Start.

```
let clockStartTime: Int = 200

enum ClockState {
    case Started
    case Stopped
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer: NSTimer = NSTimer()
    var counter: Int = clockStartTime
    var clockState: ClockState = .Stopped

    @IBOutlet weak var btnStart: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateButtonTitle()
    }

    @IBAction func btnStartPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        if self.clockState == .Stopped
        {
            self.clockState = .Started

            let timeIncrement:NSTimeInterval = 0.5
            let repeating:Bool = true
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeIncrement, target:self, selector: #selector(self.updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: repeating)
        }
        else {
            self.clockState = .Stopped
            timer.invalidate()
        }

    }

    func updateCounter() {
        if counter > 50
        {
            counter -= 1
        }
        else {
            counter = 0
            timer.invalidate()
        }

        updateButtonTitle()
    }

    func updateButtonTitle()
    {
        self.btnStart.titleLabel?.text = String(counter)
    }
}
```

Issue: When pressing the button to pause the timer, the button label text gets reset to "Start" when it should be the number the user pressed to pause it on.

Question: How do I stop Swift from resetting the contents of the button label to "Start"?

Comment: I think the issue is that `self.btnStart.titleLabel?.text = String(counter)` is wrong and should be `self.btnStart.setTitle(String(counter), forState: UIControlState.Normal)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've since solved the issue.

It was indeed related to how the button text is changed.

`self.btnStart.setTitle(String(counter), forState: UIControlState.Normal)`

Thanks

\Closed